# I am using tinymce, Is it possible to apply for only one textarea

Tags: javascript, tinymce, textarea

I am using tinymce, I have multiple text areas on my page. Is it possible to apply for only one textarea,

1 text area is for description
validation is like below

```
var text = tinyMCE.get('txtdesc').getContent();
```

But i have more 3 more text areas in my page so tineMCE should not apply for all these text areas

How can i apply only for one text area

```
// this is my tinyMCE code 
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced"
    });

// /tinyMCE
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For the `textarea` assign a `class=""` to textarea  property, this will support for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        //mode : "textareas",
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector : "myTextEditor",
        theme : "simple"
    });
</script>

<textarea id="txtdesc" name="txtdesc" class="myTextEditor" rows="6" cols="96" ></textarea>
```

Comment: How to  bind it with attr "id" of textarea.

Comment: mode : "exact", elements: "textarea_id" | Please use this in code to use

Answer (score 50):

In the TinyMCE 3.x config you can put class selectors or deselectors to specifically enable or disable TinyMCE on textareas with certain classes, just put the `class=""` attribute on your textarea.

```
editor_deselector : "mceNoEditor" // class="mceNoEditor" will not have tinyMCE
editor_selector : "mceEditor", // class="mceEditor" will.
```

[Source](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:editor_deselector).

---

As of TinyMCE 4.0.x

```
selector: "textarea", // Select all textarea
selector: "textarea.editme", // Select all textarea with the class editme
selector : "textarea:not(.mceNoEditor)", // Select all textarea exluding the mceNoEditor class
```

[Source](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:selector).

Comment: Also works on textarea with a specific ID, e.g. `selector: "textarea#myTAID"`

Answer (score 6):

In TinyMCE 4.x  there is no deselector so you can use normal css to determine which textareas are selected and which are not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea:not(.textarea-no-styles)",
 });
</script>
```

Comment: I thought that I would add that multiple classes may be entered here, separated by commas, to be excluded: `selector: "textarea:not(.regTextarea1,.regTextarea2)"`

Answer (score 3):

In TinyMCE 4.x, you can use editor_selector option , but before that make sure you must updated mode to 'specific_textareas'

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  tinymce.init({
    mode : "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector : "mceEditor",
    });
</script>
```

Also add css class same as editor_selector value in your textarea, as per above example it should look like this:

```
<textarea id='textarea1' class='mceEditor'>first text area</textarea>
```

now, editor will be added in those textarea that have a class named 'mceEditor'.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me on version 4.6.4, and it's simpler :

I've just appended #my_text_area_id to my selector as follows

```
selector: 'textarea#elm1'
<textarea id="elm1" ...>...</textarea>
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a [`selector`](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:selector).

```
selector: "#text_area_id", // Select with textarea id
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.5.4/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question... it doesn't even seem to be related to TinyMCE at all. Please see [answer] and [edit] your answer to add more information to explain how to solve the problem.